# Difference between x = -5.abs() and print(x.abs())?

Tags: dart

```
void main() {
   var x = -5.abs();
   print(x);
}
```

Will be -5.

But:

```
void main() {
   var x = -5;
   print(x.abs());
}
```

Will be 5.

`-5` is an object, and the result of `-5.abs()` will be connected to `x`. But we still see `-5`. Could you please correct me where I wrong?

Comment: What I think is happening in the first case is `-(5.abs())`, i.e., the absolute value of 5 (which is 5), which is then negated.

Answer (score 3):

I think what Dart does is:
`var x = (-1)*5.abs();`

You can use `var x = (-5).abs();` to get 5

Comment: It is suddenly for me:) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
   var x = -5.abs();
   print(x);
}
```

is almost certainly parsed as

```
void main() {
   var x = -(5.abs());
   print(x);
}
```

and since 5 is already positive, it comes back unchanged.  And then you negate that result.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know is this Dart parsing specific? Or is it a standard behavior like an order of arithmetical operations (*,:,-,+, etc.)?

Comment: I've seen both types of precedence for prefix minus over the years.